# Imagem alterando de posição quando inserida dentro de um link

Tags: html, link, slider, img

Estou tentando criar um "slider" semelhante ao da Netflix. Montei a estrutura e deu tudo certo, mas quando coloco as imagens dentro de links que levam às páginas correspondentes, elas desalinham. Segue o erro e o código:

[image: slider desalinhado]

```
    <div class="slider">
        <a href=index.html><img src="Farmacologia.svg"></a>
        <img src="Farmacologia.svg">
        <a href=index.html><img src="Farmacologia.svg"></a>
        <img src="Farmacologia.svg">
        <img src="Farmacologia.svg"> 
        <img src="Farmacologia.svg"> 
        <img src="Farmacologia.svg"> 
        <img src="Farmacologia.svg"> 
        <img src="Farmacologia.svg">
        <img src="Farmacologia.svg">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você deve adicionar o atributo align da tag 'img', para definir a posição das imagens.
exemplo:
`<img src="Farmacologia.svg" align='middle'>` (pra alinhar no meio, por exemplo)

*ou right pra alinhar pra direita, left pra esquerda.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Fala João, tudo certo?

Percebes que têm imagens fora da tag < a> ? Certamente se colocares todas as imagens dentro da tag < a> resolverá o teu problema.

```
    <div class="slider">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="Farmacologia.svg"></a>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="Farmacologia.svg"></a>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="Farmacologia.svg"></a>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="Farmacologia.svg"></a>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="Farmacologia.svg"></a>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="Farmacologia.svg"></a>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="Farmacologia.svg"></a>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="Farmacologia.svg"></a>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="Farmacologia.svg"></a>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="Farmacologia.svg"></a>
    </div>
```

Na classe "slider", coloca os seguintes estilos:

```
.slider {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Róger. Infelizmente não deu certo, já tentei fazer assim e todas as imagens ficam desalinhadas... Elas ficam certas quando coloco a tag <a> fora da div mas assim eu não consigo especificar o link que cada imagem leva.

Comment: Eu editei minha resposta, da uma olhada, vê se resolve.